# Segmentation fault on a C++ client/server application at printf

Tags: c++, printf, client-server

I am trying to read the username/password from the client and transmit it to the server. I am also trying dynamic allocation of the strings(I don t know much about it, trying to learn it) and I am pretty sure there is the problem. On the last 2 printf's I get a segmentation fault(core dumped).

```
int nrbytes;
char *Usercl,*Passcl;
if( read (tdl.cl, &nrbytes, sizeof(int)) <= 0 )
{
    printf("[server]Thread - %d\n",tdl.idThread);
    perror("Read() error\n ");
}

Usercl = new char[nrbytes+1];
if( read (tdl.cl, &Usercl, sizeof(nrbytes)) <= 0 )
{
    printf("[server]Thread - %d\n",tdl.idThread);
    perror("Read() error\n ");
}

if( read (tdl.cl, &nrbytes, sizeof(int)) <= 0 )
{
    printf("[server]Thread - %d\n",tdl.idThread);
    perror("Read() error\n ");
}
Passcl = new char[nrbytes+1];
if( read (tdl.cl, &Passcl, sizeof(nrbytes)) <= 0 )
{
    printf("[server]Thread - %d\n",tdl.idThread);
    perror("Read() error\n ");
}
printf("[server]Thread - %d\n. User:%s\n",tdl.idThread,Usercl);
printf("[server]Thread - %d\n. Pass:%s\n",tdl.idThread,Passcl);
```

I get a segmentation fault(core dumped) on the last 2 printf's.

Comment: I'm guessing the data you read in isn't null terminated.

Comment: Also, `if( read (tdl.cl, &Usercl, sizeof(nrbytes)) <= 0 )` ---> `if( read (tdl.cl, Usercl, nrbytes) <= 0 )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I did everything you told me and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your Usercl and Passcl are already pointers. Remove '&' on both of their read calls.